# after executing, window.setTimeout() throws 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, settimeout

Below is my code in question:

```
// if any alerts, set them to auto-close
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.each( $('.alert'), function(){
    closeAlert( this );
  });
}, 2000);

function closeAlert( alert ){
  $(alert).fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(alert).close();
  });
};
```

So the code above is used to auto-close bootstrap alerts after a couple of seconds. It works perfectly, however immediately after the `closeAlert()` method closes the alert, my console gets the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
the error is referencing the last bracket of the `closeAlert()` method.

Why am I getting an undefined error when the function is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
$(alert).close();
```

Should be like this

```
$(alert).hide();
```

The error is raising because Jquery does not have a function called `.close()`

---

Full code would be,

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.each( $('.alert'), function(){
    closeAlert( this );
  });
}, 2000);

function closeAlert( alert ){
  $(alert).fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(alert).hide();
  });
};
```

Comment: @AntoKing Let them free.. we cannot stop them.. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistance.:) so the .close() method must be added by bootstrap because it still worked. Anyway I've replaced it with .hide().remove() to remove it from the DOM.

Comment: @Prefix `.remove()` is enough for that... :)